# Get the value of the first column in a selected row in datatables

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I'm trying to get the value of the first column of a select row using DataTables. I have read many posts and solutions to this. It should be simple but whenever I use the "....data()" method, I get an '.... is undefined' error.

The first column contains the key, which I will use to get the detailed record and display in an adjacent tab. However, I have tried many things and just cannot seem to get the value.

The table is populated by data returned by an API call, which works fine. The structure looks like this in HTML:

```
<table id="Proposal-table" class="table table-hover non-hover"
       data-toggle="Proposal-table" style="width:100%">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th data-field="ID_PROPOSAL" id="ID">ID</th>
             <th data-field="STR_INST_REF">Institution</th>
             <th data-field="NME_PROPOSAL">Name</th>
             <th data-field="STR_DESC" data-width="900" data-widthunit="px">Description</th>
             <th data-field="CNT_TERM">Term</th>
             <th data-field="AMT_TOTAL_VALUE">Value</th>
             <th data-field="AMT_TOTAL_COST">Cost</th>
             <th data-field="CCY_PROPOSAL">CCY.</th>
             <th data-field="PCT_INT_RATE_LOW">Rate Low</th>
             <th data-field="PCT_INT_RATE_HIGH">Rate High</th>
             <th data-field="IND_PROD_TYPE">Type</th>
             <th data-field="IND_STATUS">Status</th>
             <th data-field="DTE_CREATED">Created</th>
             <th data-field="DTM_MAINT">Maint</th>
             <!--    <th>Action TBC</th> -->
         </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

The table is defined, filled, and made clickable here:

```
  <script>
      function buildTable() {
          // Define table to display list from API...
          var propTable = $('#Proposal-table').DataTable( {
              dom: '<"row"<"col-md-12"<"row"<"col-md-6"B><"col-md-6"f> > ><"col-md-12"rt> <"col-md-12"<"row"<"col-md-5"i><"col-md-7"p>>> >',
              buttons: {
                  buttons: [
                      { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn' },
                      { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn' },
                      { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn' },
                      { extend: 'print', className: 'btn' }
                  ]
              },
              "oLanguage": {
                  "oPaginate": { "sPrevious": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-left"><line x1="19" y1="12" x2="5" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 19 5 12 12 5"></polyline></svg>', "sNext": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-right"><line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 5 19 12 12 19"></polyline></svg>' },
                  "sInfo": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
                  "sSearch": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-search"><circle cx="11" cy="11" r="8"></circle><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="16.65" y2="16.65"></line></svg>',
                  "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search...",
                  "sLengthMenu": "Results :  _MENU_",
              },
              "stripeClasses": [],
              "lengthMenu": [7, 10, 20, 50],
              "pageLength": 7
          } );

          // Call API to get data...
          $.get("http://path to API/v1/proposal/list/", function (data) {
              var listObj = data.output;
              console.log(listObj);
              $(function () {
                  $('#Proposal-table').bootstrapTable({
                      data: listObj
                  });
                  //console.log(propTable);
              });
          }, "json");

          // Make the table clickable...
          $('#Proposal-table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
              var trow = $(this).closest('tr');
              var id = trow.attr('data-index');
              console.log(trow);
              var prop = propTable.row(trow);
              console.log(prop);

              var selectedRow = propTable.row('tr.selected');
              var selectedRowData = propTable.row(selectedRow).data();
              console.log(selectedRow);
              console.log(selectedRowData.value["ID"]);
              console.log(selectedRowData.ID_PROPOSAL);

              //var colval = prop.cell(0).data();
              //var propID = propTable.row('.selected').data()["ID_PROPOSAL"];
              //var rowData = propTable.rows( { selected: true } ).data()[0]['ID_PROPOSAL'];
              //var rowdata = propTable.row(this).data()[0];
              //console.log(rowData);

              //var idx = propTable.cell('.selected', 0).index();
              //console.log(idx);

              //console.log(rowdata);
              // console.log(aData);
              //var idx = propTable.cell('.selected', 0).index();
              //var prop = propTable.row( idx.row ).data();
              //var id2 = propTable.row({ selected: true } ).data()[0]['ID_PROPOSAL'];
              //var idx = $.inArray( tr.attr('id'), prop );
              //console.log(idx);
              //console.log(prop);
              //console.log(id2);

              // call API
              $.get("http://path to API/v1/proposal/list1/"+id.toString()+"/", function (data) {
                  var dataObj = data.output;
                  console.log(dataObj);
                  displayProposal(dataObj);
              }, "json");
          });
      }
     window.onload = buildTable;
  </script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

After much investigation, I have resolved the problem I was having. I can't pinpoint exactly what the problem was as I changed a few things and tried a different approach.

I had used a separate $.get to get my data and loaded it into the table using a Bootstraptable method.

I decided to use the DataTable ajax option to get my data and load the table with that. In addition I explicitly defined the columns (and data) as part of the table initiation.

So I added this to the table definition:

```
          "ajax": {
              "url":"http://path to data/proposal/list/",
              "type":"GET",
              "dataSrc": "output"
          },
          columns:[
              { data: "ID_PROPOSAL"},
              { data: "STR_INST_REF"},
              { data: "NME_PROPOSAL"},
              { data: "STR_DESC"},
              { data: "CNT_TERM"},
              { data: "AMT_TOTAL_VALUE"},
              { data: "AMT_TOTAL_COST"},
              { data: "CCY_PROPOSAL"},
              { data: "CNT_USER_ID"},
              { data: "PCT_INT_RATE_LOW"},
              { data: "PCT_INT_RATE_HIGH"},
              { data: "IND_PROD_TYPE"},
              { data: "IND_STATUS"},
              { data: "DTE_CREATED"},
              { data: "DTM_MAINT"},
          ],
          select: true,
```

Then I was able to access the row().data() method successfully using this below:

```
      //Make table Clickable and process click...
      $('#Proposal-table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
          var dta = propTable.row( this ).data();
          var id = dta["ID_PROPOSAL"];
```